# Responsive static graphs with cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js to draw a graph that I don't need to zoom or navigate, so it basically looks like a static image. Even though, I would like it to be responsive, in the sense that it should scale up/down when the viewport resizes. I have tried to make the cytoscape container resizable by setting its width as 100%, but it does not work. I have also tried calling cytoscape.resize() and cytoscape.fit() after the window resize event but it has no effect.

The initialisation options that I am using are:

```
cytoscape({
      container: cyContainer,
      zoomingEnabled: false,
      autoungrabify: true,
      autounselectify: true,
      userZoomingEnabled: false,
      panningEnabled: false,
      userPanningEnabled: false,
      boxSelectionEnabled: false,
      style: ...
```

where cyContainer is a div with width (as percentage) and height as px.

Is is possible to make it responsive?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the viewport pan and zoom if you disable those features (i.e. zoom and pan are immutable).  Just disable the appropriate user interactions.